# GParted Live is telling me I have 2 bad sectors on my system drive

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, partitioning, gparted

I just wanted to use GParted on my laptop to resize my partitions.
Unfortunately, GParted said the operation couldn't be done, then
there are 2 bad sectors on the partition. 
It's the system partition, and I'm a bit worried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always attempt a repair, but bad sectors nearly always lead to other troubles sooner or later. I would attempt a recovery of as much data as possible and change your hard drive ASAP.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice. I'll try the repair first, and maybe relocate my Windows partition. Do you know any good opensource that could help me out to find exactely where the sectors are located, appart of Ultimate boot?

Comment: I agree backup is essential

Comment: Backup's done! Shall I low-format the HDD and reinstall Windows?

Comment: I'd junk the hard disk and get a new one, unless it's still under warranty.

Comment: OK, I think I won't take the risk, and just buy a new HDD...

Comment: That is the best thing to do - the fact is, they usually go bad by mechanical failure, you can mark a sector as bad and it will be skipped but there is always a high chance it will get worse before to long. To fix, I am not sure of the Linux commands, but I think Gparted can do it... If not, use your Windows install disk and go to the recovery console and type 1. "c:" 2. "chkdsk /F" (all without the quotes), this should be able to scan and test... but again, I wouldn't trust it now!